# Permissões de JavaScript e ActiveX no IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, iis-7, iis

Olá, uma aplicação em Asp.Net MVC usa Scripting.FileSystemObject para criar arquivos textos. Na máquina de desenvolvimento funciona normalmente, esta aplicação foi publicada em um servidor com IIS e também funcionou normalmente, mas quando fui publicá-la em um outro servidor IIS ela não gera mais os arquivos textos e quando coloco o IE em modo debug para ver o por que ele mostra erro bem na linha do javascript quer gera o arquivo com a mensagem de permissão negada.

O primeiro servidor IIS que eu publiquei e funcionou é um que já tinha outras aplicações .net e este que não está funcionando é um IIS que foi instalado a pouco tempo, então se o outro foi feita alguma configuração este não tem.

Então a minha dúvida é: precisa fazer alguma configuração no IIS para que seja possível gerar arquivos textos por JavaScript ou para usar ActiveX como Scripting.FileSystemObject?

Comment: Máquina de desenvolvimento é uma coisa, você tem controle sobre tudo .Tem que desenvolver para funcionar em máquina que você não pode ter tudo escancarado. E você pode por o que você quiser nas páginas, é só um texto, não tem restrição. Se vai funcionar é outro problema. Depende do que você fez.

Answer (score 0):

Isso não tem nada a ver com o IIS ou o com o Asp.NET, o Javascript é client-side (não vamos entrar no mérito do Node.js, que é o Javascript server-side porque não está no contexto da pergunta) e por isso ao usar o ActiveX em questão ele precisa de permissão da máquina onde se deseja criar o arquivo, que pelo que você descreveu é na máquina do cliente (quem acessa o site).

Afinal o que você deseja realmente ? Criar o arquivo de texto na máquina de cada cliente que acessar o site ou no servidor onde está rodando a aplicação (site) ?

**Se for no servidor**, você tem que fazer isso no seu controller (não na view, bom pode ser na view, mas por questões de design não faça na view) usando System.IO.* (mais precisamente System.IO.File.*)

**Se for na máquina do cliente**, qual seria o motivo para isso ? Porque dificilmente você terá sucesso, imagina que você está criando um arquivo TXT, mas se isso fosse possível, qualquer um poderia criar um arquivo .BAT, .EXE, etc fazer o caminho inverso (acessar arquivos) e roubar arquivos do disco local só pela pessoa ter acessado o site...
Se for realmente preciso, você vai precisar convencer (e ensinar) cada usuário a liberar o acesso do ActiveX no PC dele, e pelo que eu saiba ActiveX só funciona no IE (nem sei se no EDGE ainda existe isso)
Outra solução caso precise escrever na máquina do usuário é criar uma ferramenta executável (.exe) ou uma extensão do navegador (ai é uma para cada navegador né) que faça a tarefa e essa ferramenta/extensão se comunique com seu site (ou não, se não for preciso).